# Error during compilation of SDL test

Tags: c++, c, sdl, sdl-2

I'm learning to programming with SDL2. Currently, I'm making a basic exercise. My program load a background image, and a complete sprite sheet on the background. But I'm having problems while executing the program. When I execute the binary, the program window closes immediately by itself; I cant see anything. I think it is a problem with the main loop, but it looks right for me. This is my code

```
#include "SDL.h"


void main () {

int gameover = 0;


SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);

SDL_Window* TheWindow;
SDL_Renderer* RenderEngine;
SDL_Surface* LoadedSurface;
SDL_Surface* LoadedImage;
SDL_Texture* CharacterImg;
SDL_Texture* BackgroundImg;

TheWindow = SDL_CreateWindow("Character Test",
    SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 640, 580, SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE);

RenderEngine = SDL_CreateRenderer( TheWindow, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);

LoadedSurface= SDL_LoadBMP("./maptest.bmp");
BackgroundImg = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface( RenderEngine, LoadedSurface);
SDL_FreeSurface(LoadedSurface);

LoadedImage = SDL_LoadBMP("./sprite.bmp");
CharacterImg = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface( RenderEngine, LoadedImage);
SDL_FreeSurface(LoadedImage);



SDL_Event event;

 while (!gameover)
{

  if (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {

  switch (event.type) {

        case SDL_QUIT:
         gameover = 1;
        break;

        case SDL_KEYDOWN:
        switch (event.key.keysym.sym) {
        case SDLK_ESCAPE:
        case SDLK_q:
         gameover = 1;
                break;
            }   
         }
      break;
      }

    SDL_RenderClear(RenderEngine);
    SDL_RenderCopy(RenderEngine, BackgroundImg, NULL, NULL);
    SDL_RenderCopy(RenderEngine, CharacterImg, 120, 80);
    SDL_RenderPresent(RenderEngine);


   }



    SDL_Quit();



}
```

Comment: If your program runs, then it is not an error during compilation.

Comment: Also, have you tried just adding some printf's for logging at critical points and then run it from the command line? That should get you more answers...

Answer (score 3):

Your code will quit the `while`-loop if *any* `SDL_PollEvent` happens:

```
while (!gameover)
  {
    if (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) //Any SDL_PollEvent that gets into if...
      {
        switch (event.type)
          {     
          case SDL_QUIT:
            gameover = 1;
            break;
          case SDL_KEYDOWN:
            switch (event.key.keysym.sym)
              {
              case SDLK_ESCAPE:
              case SDLK_q:
                gameover = 1;
                break;
              }   
          }
        break;     //...will eventually hit this break if it didn't break before
      }
    SDL_RenderClear(RenderEngine);
    SDL_RenderCopy(RenderEngine, BackgroundImg, NULL, NULL);
    SDL_RenderCopy(RenderEngine, CharacterImg, 120, 80);
    SDL_RenderPresent(RenderEngine); 
  }
```

Comment: Yes that last break will drop the program out of the while loop. Also though, the code really could use some safety checks in the way of checking for NULL's after creating/loading resources.

Comment: Those Egyptian brackets will get you.  Note how EOF cleans it up so it's obvious where the problem lies.